# How to get values of form in sencha touch outside the form handler?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have form inside panel . How to get values of form using getValues() now??

```
var myForm = new Ext.form.Panel({
  id:'form1',
  items:[
    { fields ...}
  ]
});
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
  id:'myPanel',
  layout:'vbox',
  items:[
    myForm,
   {
     other fields
   },
   {
    xtype : 'button',
    text : 'save',
    handler : function() {
    }
   }
  ]
});
```

Now

```
myForm.getValues();//not working
Ext.getCmp('form1').getValues();//not working
```

How to get values of form outside the form . Any help??

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `new` before `Ext.form.Panel`..

double check the code before posting question in SO

```
var myForm = new Ext.form.Panel({
  id:'form1',
  items:[
    { fields ...}
  ]
});
```